# What is the solution of 'can't find java SE sdk installed in specified folder' in sqldeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed oracle database. I want to work using sqldeveloper. I downloaded the latest version of it. After extracting it when I intend to run it, it shows this messages.[please specify the path to java jdk home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byhwu.png) and ['can't find a java SE SDK installed at"c:\program files(*86)\java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin"'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8jLn.png)

I can't find any answer for this problem. I tried installing java again, there is no 'jdk' folder in my sqldeveloper folder(latest version). I can't understand what can I do?

Comment: Check if your windows is 32 o 64 bits, then install java and sqldev for that architecture.

Answer (score 12):

There could be two things here:

1. Don't point SQL Developer to the bin folder - browse to the parent folder
2. You don't actually have an SDK installed there.

If it's the second point, the following might help.  (and if it's not, it will probably sound quite patronising, sorry about that).

Java comes in two flavours.

Unless you're a developer, you normally just need the runtime (Java Runtime Environment, or JRE), which is what you normally end up with if you go to download java.

But if you want to write programs in Java or, it appears, use SQL developer, you need the version of Java that lets you write java programs, and compile them to something that will run on the Java runtime.  That's the Java Development Kit, or JDK.

If you google "download java", you'll end up here: 
https://java.com/en/download/
You get the "runtime" or JRE.

But if you google "download jdk", you end up here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Which is more likely to be what you want.

After you've downloaded and installed that, point SQL Developer at the folder that that one has installed into.  You can check you've got a JDK because there'll be a program called javac in the bin folder.

Alternatively, some of the SQL Developer downloads include the JDK as well, so if you make sure you download one of those, it should solve the issue.  (This is probably what @Mate is suggesting in that comment).

Comment: I have downloaded JDK1.8.0_152. In my previous jdk netbean was automatically installed. For this version how this will work?

Comment: One more question, what is the username and password when creating a new connection?

Comment: "browse to the parent folder" worked for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Pointing to the parent folder worked for me too on Windows 10

Answer (score 6):

You can find `JDK` in this folder when you install oracle.
choose `c:\oracle\x32orx64\client\jdk` directory.

It will solve the problem with SQL Developer because I had to move it to another directory since it asks for admin rights every time non-admin run it.

```
#sqldeveloper
#admin
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I also encounter this issue and stuck about 1 hours to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem in the past.

If you are facing this problem on a Windows 10 64 bit OS, Then install the SQL developer tool with JDK, even if you already have JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I kept getting the following errors when I tried to install SQL developer on a virtual machine:
Cannot find a Java SE SDK installed at path...
and
Unable to find Java Virtual MAchine
and
SQL Developer crashed on startup

In my case, the solution was to move the downloaded installation folder from the virtual machine shared folder to the virtual mahine C:\ folder and run it from there. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

trying creating/editing JAVA_HOME environmental variable by going to my computer properties.give the variable value as the jdk location in your machine